# Wubi installation did not prompt me for username or password; now I'm stuck as a guest

Tags: installation, windows

I used the windows installer for Ubuntu but it only lets me login as a guest. I think it is because it never prompted me for a username or password during installation. Now, I obviously can't do anything that requires admin rights. How do I gain admin rights?

Answer (score 0):

I had that happen to me as well. You should be prompted for a password during the install process. If not, use Windows Control Panel, add/remove programs to remove ubuntu and start over. Sounds like a pain, but it doesn't actually take that long.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to take terminal [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

```
useradd username

passwd username
```